# If this then show that

Tags: crystal-reports

I am pulling data from the AS400 and my date formats are in CYYMMDD so I have the data converted using the following:

```
Local StringVar x := ToText({SMPWAYB.WBSHPD}, "0");
Local NumberVar c := (ToNumber(LEFT(x, 1)) + 1) * 10;
x := RIGHT(x, 6);
Local NumberVar y := ToNumber(ToText(c, "0") & LEFT(x, 2));
x := RIGHT(x, 4);
Local NumberVar m := ToNumber(LEFT(x, 2));
x := RIGHT(x, 2);
Local NumberVar d :=ToNumber(x);

Dateserial(y,m,d)
```

If there is no date value in the field, it shows 0.00, and with the conversion it shows 11/30/99.

I want to keep the date conversion but show N/A if the date is 11/30/99. How do I add this to my formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this at the end:

```
if Dateserial(y,m,d) = CDate("11/30/99")
then "NA"
else ToText(Dateserial(y,m,d))
```